# Load Picklist value dynamically using javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, picklist, datetime

I am in a situation to load values of picklist dynamically using javascript.

By Javascript am getting Date and Time of the given country using google geolocation and timezone api. From the catched TIME, I want to load the time values after 4 hours. For example

if catched time is 10:00 AM, picklist values should start from 2:00PM, 3:00PM, 4:00PM, 5:00PM......11:00PM

How to do this? am pasting what I am getting from timezone.

```
function findAssetTimeZone(Latitude, Longitude) {

        var requestUrl =
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/' +
            'json' +
            '?location=' + Latitude + ',' + Longitude +
            '&timestamp=' + getTimeStamp(new Date().getTime()) +
            '&sensor=' + 'false'

        $.ajax({
                    url: requestUrl,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(timeZone) {
                    debugger;
                        if (timeZone['status'] == 'OK') {
                        var exactdate;
                        var currentDate = new Date();
//assetUTCDate gets the exact date and time 
                        var assetUTCDate = new Date(Date.UTC(currentDate.getUTCFullYear(), currentDate.getUTCMonth(), currentDate.getUTCDate(),
                            currentDate.getUTCHours(), currentDate.getUTCMinutes(), currentDate.getUTCSeconds(), currentDate.getUTCMilliseconds()));

                        assetUTCDate = assetUTCDate.addSeconds((timeZone['rawOffset'] + timeZone['dstOffset']));

                        exactdate = ExactDateTime(assetUTCDate);
                        assetdateString = exactdate.toGMTString();
                        assetdateString = convertGMTStringToReadableFormat(assetdateString);
                        document.getElementById("datetime").value = assetdateString;
                       } else {

                        resetAssetTimeZoneFields();

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this question has nothing to do with Salesforce?

Answer (score 2):

Following page loads picklist with 12 different hours, starting from given time + 4 hours.

Where following line loads initial time:

```
var startDate = new Date("2016-07-15T10:00:00");
```

VF:

```
<apex:page >
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var startDate = new Date("2016-07-15T10:00:00");
        document.querySelectorAll('[id$="startTime"]')[0].innerHTML = formatAMPM(startDate);
        appendSelectOption(new Date(startDate.getTime()+3*3600000));
    }

    function appendSelectOption( newDate ) {
        var selectList = document.querySelectorAll('[id$="timeOption"]')[0];  
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            var newDate = new Date(newDate.getTime()+3600000);
            option.value = newDate.getHours();
            option.text = formatAMPM(newDate);
            selectList.appendChild(option);
        }
    }

    function formatAMPM(date) {
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
        var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
        return strTime;
    }
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:outputText id="startTime" label="Start Time"/>
                <apex:selectList id="timeOption" size="1" label="Time Option">
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="--None--" itemLabel="--None--" id="vfOption"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Result:

[image]